# Using StructureMap and IDependencyResolver, can't use Interface on Strong typed view and create action

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-3, structuremap

I have a brand new project, asp.net mvc 3.

It's all pretty standard, using StructureMap and Nhibernate.

I have 3 projetcs, Core, Infrastructure and UI.

The StructureMap wiring is working just fine, the Index action on a Sample controller is working perfectly.

But, on my create view, I've set the @model to be something like

```
@model Project.Core.Domain.ISample
```

On the Controller I have a normal post method :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ISample sample)
    {
        try
        {
            _repo.Save(sample);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting the "Cannot create an instance of an interface." error.

The last executed lines on the stack are :

> [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an instance of an interface.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +98
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +199
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +572
>      System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +449
>      System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +317

I would expect that mvc would use the DependencyResolver internally, if it did, it would be able to create a concrete instance of my ISample interface...but there's a big chance that I understood something completely wrong and this makes no sense...

If I make this simple change to the controller, everything works normally :

```
public ActionResult Create(Sample sample)
```

I may be wrong, but this seems wrong to me, everything else is able to use the interface to communicate, why would I have to use the concrete class on the Create action ? This would take away some of the flexibility that the interface gave me.

Does anyone have any idea on how to proceed or if I'm on the wrong track ?

Thanks for your attention.

**This is how I got to what I wanted with Darin's help**

I've created a new GenericModelBinder (maybe the name could be better)

```
    public class GenericModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        var obj = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(modelType);
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, obj.GetType());
    }
}
```

And in global.asax I've added :

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new GenericModelBinder();
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a custom model binder for the `ISample` type for this to work. ASP.NET MVC uses the default model binder when it invokes a controller action in order to instantiate the action parameters from the request values.

```
public class MyISampleModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Here you need to return the proper instance of the ISample interface
        // based on the request values or some other rules you need
    }
}
```

and then in `Application_Start` register this binder:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ISample), new MyISampleModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I stumbled upon something like it during my research, but what got me thinking is, why would I need a special model binder for each model ? And why wouldn't the default implementation use the DependecyResolver ? It is able to create the concrete class, it should just call the dependency resolver for that instance...or this would be completely wrong ? Thanks again!